# Functions of form $f(z)/f(z^*)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am doing my research in mathematical physics, and in the process I am getting functions of complex variable $z$ of form
$F(z) = \frac{f(z)}{f(z^*)}$

In my case $f$ doesn't have any interesting properties (except for being analytic). Also, $f(z)$ takes complex values on real axis, so $f(z^*) \ne f(z)^*$ in general. Is there a name for the class of functions of form $F$? Are there any notable properties?